# How do I get coordinates of boolean 'True' from pd.dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, coordinates

I have a png that I turned into pd.DataFrame which contains booleans. For a white pixel I'm getting 'False' and for black pixel 'True'. I would like to generate DXF diagram. For that I'm trying to get coordinates for every 'True' on the dataframe so I could connect them later on to draw the line.

This is the code I currently have:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = Image.open('/home/sinushas/Downloads/Brezynio_Konvertavimas/test.png')
thresh = 200
fn = lambda x : 255 if x > thresh else 0
r = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
r.save('/home/sinushas/Downloads/Brezynio_Konvertavimas/test_converted.png')

im = Image.open('/home/sinushas/Downloads/Brezynio_Konvertavimas/test_converted.png')
im2arr = np.array(im) # im2arr.shape: height x width x channel

df = pd.DataFrame(im2arr)
df = (df == False)
```

This is the pd.Dataframe generated:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   True    True    True    True    True    True    False   False
3   False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
4   False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
5   False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
6   False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
7   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
8   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
9   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
```

I expect to get the following coordinates:
(2:3),(2:4),(2:5),(2:6),(2:7),(2:8),(3:5),(3:6),(4:5),(4:6),(5:5),(6:6),(6:5),(6:6)

I have not found a working piece of code that could get me any of the coordinates from the Dataframe..
Thing I have tried:

```
result = im2arr.where('True')

df.sort_index() 

res = [i for i, val in enumerate(df) if val]
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3):

## [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

to make a [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
df2=df.stack()
coordinates=[*df2[df2].index]
```

---

```
#print(coordinates)
[(2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 5),
 (5, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 4),
 (6, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
coord = np.where(df)

coordinates = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(coord[0], coord[1])]
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 5),
 (5, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 4),
 (6, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.nonzero`:

```
[(x,y) for x,y in zip(*np.nonzero(df.values))]
```

Output:

```
[(2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 5),
 (5, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 4),
 (6, 5)]

​
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `pandas` for this. And you don't have to read it again. You can even use `L` in `.point(fn, mode='L')`

```
r = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
r.save(...)

data = np.where(r)          # [[y1,y2,...], [x1,x2,...], ]
points = list(zip(*data))   # [[y1,x1], [y2,x2], ...]

print(points)
```

You can use directly `where()` on `r` to get list with `[[y1,y2,...], [x1,x2,...]]`.

And then you can use `zip()` to create pairs `[y1, x1]`, `[y2,x2]`, etc.

**EDIT:** For other pixels you can use `~` to negate values in `r`

```
data = np.where(~r)          # other pixels
```

---

Array works with coordinates `(row, columns)` which means `(y, x)` - like in your expected data `(2,3), (2,4)` - but if you will need `(x, y)` then use:

```
points = list(zip(data[1], data[0]))
```

eventually

```
points = [(x,y) for y,x in zip(*data)]
```

---

**EDIT:** You don't need even `.point()`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')

arr = np.array(img)

#data = np.where( arr > 200 )    # for white pixels
#data = np.where( ~(arr > 200) ) # for black pixels too
data = np.where(arr < 200) # for black pixels

points_y_x = list(zip(*data))
points_x_y = list(zip(data[1], data[0]))

print(points_y_x)
print(points_x_y)
```

Comment: If I use your code from the edit it seems to give me all the cordinates from the image that is coloured white not black

Comment: when I tested your code then it gives `True` for white pixels so my code also gives coordinates for the same elements. But you can use `< 200` instead of `> 200` to get black instead of white.

Comment: in first version you can use `~` to negate values - `data = np.where(~r)`

Comment: I see problem. I didn't use `DataFrame` and I missed your last line `df = (df == False)` which negate values in `DataFrame`. So you have to use `~r` in my code to nagate values too. In second example use  `~(arr > 200)` instead of `arr > 200` or simply `arr < 200`

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me, I will try it out!